# Model - field based on values in other fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've literally just started learning MVC.

I have created a simple model:

```
public class StaffMember
{
    public Guid StaffMemberId { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Observation> Observations { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have decided that I want to include a drop down list of all `StaffMembers` on the create page for the observation records. I manage to do that with the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.StaffMemberId,
                          new SelectList(Model.StaffMembers,
                                         "StaffMemberId", 
                                         "Forename", 
                                         Model.StaffMemberId), 
                          "-- Select Staff Member --")
```

This works perfectly, although, you'll notice that I can only include a single field,  `"Forename"`.

I want the drop down list to show the staff member's full name.  I tried concatenating the fields manually i.e. `"Forename" + " " + "Surname"` but that threw and exception about there being no such field as "Forename" + " " + "Surname".

My question is this - is it possible to add to my model some sort of property that is simply based on the value of two existing properties.  Something like:

```
public class StaffMember
{
    private string _fullName;

    public Guid StaffMemberId { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Observation> Observations { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return _fullName;
        }
        set
        {
            value = this.Forename + " " + this.Surname;
            _fullName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the above, but when populating my database (I'm using entity model code first), that field always has a value of `null`, even though the field shows the correct value when debugging.

I'm using the following to auto populate the db with some test data:

```
var staff = new List<StaffMember>
{
    new StaffMember
    {
        Forename = "Bob",
        Surname = "Hope",
        StaffMemberId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Team = "Test" 
    },
    new StaffMember
    {
        Forename = "Stan",
        Surname = "Laurel",
        StaffMemberId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Team = "Test"
    }
};

staff.ForEach(s => context.StaffMembers.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Any pointers would be really useful here, especially if I am approaching this in completely the wrong way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're really close with the `FullName` property.

```
public class StaffMember
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Forename + " " + this.Surname;
        }
    }
}
```

No need for a private `_fullName` since you only need to get the values of Forename and Surname. And you don't need a `set` since you won't set a value back to this model using `FullName`

Answer (score -1):

You can make this change in your Repository where you add Staff_Member

```
public void AddStaff(Staff_Member sm)
{
    String fullName = sm.Forename.ToString()+" "+sm.Surname.ToString();
    sm.FullName = fullName;
    _context.Staff_Member.Add(sm);
}
```

However, you need to have set method for FullName as well in your Staff_Member model.